# PostGIS - How st_intersects works internally?

Tags: postgis

I'm fighting against some ST_Intersect operations that returns, sometimes, topology errors.

I've been running ST_makevalid for all the goemetries that apparently have the errors, but still the error in ST_Intersects appears.

I'd like to know how ST_Intersects does behind the scenes, and if there is a way to change the internal parameters to avoid (or discovery) excactly where the errors happen.

Comment: Have you tried st_snaptogrid, and/or buffering with a very small distance? It sometimes fix geometry errors that makevalid misses

Comment: I have had issues with geography and polygon whose inner ring touches the outer ring, with no vertex on the outer ring. Because of the geography type, a reprojection is done and can lead to the "intersection" point between the 2 rings to move outside of the polygon, which is an error. The original polygon is valid though! The solution was to apply a buffer of 0 to add the missing vertex on the outer ring.

Comment: Can you post an example?  And/or open a PostGIS ticket.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostGIS geometry operations are performed with the [GEOS](https://libgeos.org/) library<sup>[1]</sup>, a C++ port of the [JTS library](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/).

The JTS documentation [describes which algorithms are used for the different geometry processing operations.](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/jts-faq.html#E1) I have not found equivalent information in the GEOS documentation. But as GEOS is a JTS port, it's likely that the informations given in the JTS documentation is also true for GEOS.

---

**[1]:** Or the SFCGAL library, but this requires [specific settings](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#reference_sfcgal).

Comment: Should this be taken to mean that `st_intersects` is not really safe to use on polygons on the surface of a spherical or ellipsoidal Earth? GEOS assumes a 2D Cartesian coordinate system, so it would be using longitude as "x" and latitude as "y".